# How to draw marker and polyline to my current location in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an android application (using Intent service and Pending intent) in which I am storing my last one hour locations (Latitude and Longitude) into database.

Now I want to draw marker and polyline from the starting point to the whole distance which I travelled. I went through many websites but I am not getting how and where to implement that in my codes.

Can any one help me out?

I have 3 class files.

**1) MainActivity-** using pending intent and requesting for location update.

**2) IntentService-** running on separate thread

**3) Database-** creating database to store the latitude and longitude values

**NOTE :** I am not using location listener in this app.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw PolyLine in GoogleMaps as below

```
googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
  .add(new LatLng(start_lat, start_lon), new LatLng(end_lat,end_lon))
  .width(5)
  .color(Color.RED));
```

The above code will draw a red colored PolyLine between the (start_lat,start_lon) and (end_lat,end_lon).Assuming that the GoogleMap object in your code is `googleMap`.

Read more about PolyLine in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes)

You can add a marker in GoogleMap as below

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
```

The above code will draw a marker at the position (10,10) with a title Hello world.

Please see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

Comment: // Can U plz go through these codes and tell what and where to write in (start_lat,start_lon), new LatLng(end_lat,end_lon)  https://github.com/14ashwani/LocationTracking

Comment: Actually I am bit confuse and not sure to write these codes into mainActivity or need to create another class file.

Comment: i mean where have you added the map?

Comment: oho..i think you need take a look at how to add maps in android..please have a look of that and then continue with this..

Comment: You are asking for resource files?

Comment: first of all you should add a map fragment to show a map..do that first and then think of adding the polyline..

Comment: Actually I did that part but there are some issues in commiting the updated project thats why I gave you the link of the project which is not yet updated

Comment: I already went through your profile but I didn't find your email id or any place where I can upload my project. May be because my reputation is very less